# Finding relationships between multiple readings from an IoT sensor network time-series data

Tags: python, time-series

I am trying to find possible relationships between a large sensor network (around 100 sensors) where data is recorded in daily intervals. Each sensor has multiple readings simultaneously (Value_X). Each row contains data in below format.

|Time|Sensor ID|Value_1|Value_2|Value_3|Value_4|

I have worked with Time series data (|Time|Sensor ID|Value_1|) where one sensor records a single data and analysed with "statsmodels" python library and but couldn't find a proper way to reduce 2D (multiple sensors,time vs multiple reading values) case for a such analysis. Any insight or direction would be highly appreciated.